# Reactjs - How to do a dynamic pattern lock feature?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, webpack, redux, locking

In reactjs, I am trying to do a pattern lock feature by referring as same as https://github.com/vkurlyan/react-pattern-lock.

As per this app, now pattern lock will work for static data, how can I do the same for dynamic data?

When I change the pattern it should go to initial page to login(unlock screen) again after providing recently changed pattern then it should get proceed to next. Right now it will stay on the same page after change the pattern.

How can I complete this feature with dynamic lock(data)?